# Phalcon Login failure (getDI)

Tags: php, authentication, dependency-injection, phalcon

I'm using PHP on IIS, Phalcon framework. I have a login controller which I'm working on (yes, password isn't encrypted yet, but that's later) but I can't seem to get it to work.

I have a form action posting to signin/doSignin. This is a snippet of the SigninController.php:

```
public function doSigninAction(){
    //$this->view->disable();
    $user = User::findFirst([
          'conditions' => 'email = :email: AND password = :password:'
        , 'bind' => [
              'email' => $this->request->getPost('email')
            , 'password' => $this->request->getPost('password')
        ]
    ]);
    if ($user){
        echo 1;
        return;
    }
    echo 2;
```

What results when I run this code is a blank page that simply reports:

```
Call to undefined method or service 'getDI'
```

Something somewhere is not lined up properly for the internals of phalcon, but I don't know what I need to check. When I change the above code to this, I get a proper rendering of the view, printing 1 for the user:

```
    $user = new User()/*::findFirst([
          'conditions' => 'email = :email: AND password = :password:'
        , 'bind' => [
              'email' => $this->request->getPost('email')
            , 'password' => $this->request->getPost('password')
        ]
    ]);*/;
    if ($user){
        echo 1;
        return;
    }
    echo 2;
```

My bootstrap is the following:

```
<?php
try {
set_include_path('c:/workspace/GIIAnalytics/app/views');

//Autoloader
$loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();
$loader->registerDirs([
      '../app/controllers/'
    , '../app/models/'
    , '../app/config/'
]);
/** For MSSQL connections */
$loader->registerNamespaces([
      "Twm\Db\Adapter\Pdo"  =>  "../app/library/db/adapter/"
    , "Twm\Db\Dialect"      =>  "../app/library/db/dialect/"
]);
$loader->register();

//Dependancy Injection
$di = new \Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault();

//Config
$configFile = __DIR__ . '/../app/config/config.json';
$config = json_decode ( file_get_contents ( $configFile ) );
$di->setShared('config',$config);

//MSSQL Database connection
$di->set("db", function() use ($di) {
    //Database info
    /** For MSSQL connections */
    $mc = $di->getDI()->getShared('config')['db'];
    $db = new Twm\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mssql($mc);
    return $db;
});

//View
$di->set('view', function(){
    $view = new \Phalcon\Mvc\View();
    $view->setViewsDir('../app/views');
    /*
    $view->registerEngines([
        '.volt' => '\Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Volt'
    ]);
    */
    return $view;
});

// Router
$di->set('router',function(){
    $router = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Router();
    $router->mount(new Routes());
    return $router;
});

// Session
$di->setShared('session', function() {
    $session = new \Phalcon\Session\Adapter\Files();
    $session->start();
    return $session;
});

//Flash Data (temp data)
$di->set('flash', function() {
    $flash = new \Phalcon\Flash\Session([
          'error'   =>  'alert alert-danger'
        , 'success' =>  'alert alert-success'
        , 'notice'  =>  'alert alert-info'
        , 'warning' =>  'alert alert-warning'
    ]);
    return $flash;
});

//Metadata
$di['modelsMetadata'] = function() {
    $metaData = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\MetaData\Memory([
          'lifetime' => 86400
        , 'prefix' => 'metaData'
    ]);
    return $metaData;
};

// custom dispatcher overrides the default
$di->set('dispatcher', function() use ($di) {
    $eventsManager = $di->getShared('eventsManager');

    // Custom ACL class
    $permission = new Permission();

    // Listen for events from the $permission class
    $eventsManager->attach('dispatch', $permission);

    $dispatcher = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher();
    $dispatcher->setEventsManager($eventsManager);
    return $dispatcher;
});

//Deploy the app
$app = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Application($di);
echo $app->handle()->getContent();

} catch(\Phalcon\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getmessage();
}
?>
```

How do I fix the dependency problem?

Comment: It seems to be an issue with your bootstrapping, I can not tell by the sample above where the issue is.

Comment: Would it help if I included the whole bootstrap then?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. Phalcon is not good about giving you the line for invalid function calls. It was in my db constructor, where I'm doing $di->getDI this got changed (along with the config reader) to this snippet:

```
//MSSQL Database connection
$di->set("db", function() use ($di) {
    //Database info
    /** For MSSQL connections */
    $mc = (array) $di->getShared('config')->db;
    $db = new Twm\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mssql($mc);
    return $db;
});
```